# Sort objects by translated properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I have a fetch request that returns objects with English properties. I want to sort these objects based on their translated (Russian) equivalents using on `NSLocalizedString`. My code is incorrectly returning the data sorted as though it were English. I'm using the following sort descriptor:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category"
                              ascending:YES
                               selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];
```

My Core Data entity is called `Good` with `category` and `name` properties. I would like an array of sort descriptors that I can pass to the fetch controller (`setSortDescriptors:`) that will sort first by translated category and then by translated name.

---

If locale is english and words in english sorting is ok. But when locale is russian or ukrainian this sorting does not working. This is uotput for sorted array for russian locale

```
Кулеры
Кулеры
Память
Память
Микрофоны
Блоки питания
Блоки питания
Звуковые карты
Видеокарты
Видеокарты
```

and its wrong. What Im doing wrong? Thanks!

**Update 1: Im testing it by**

```
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.count; i++)
{

    NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString([[sortedArray objectAtIndex: i] category], nil));
}
```

**Update 2, whole code**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *goodsFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *goodsEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Goods" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [goodsFetchRequest setEntity: goodsEntity];
    NSError * error = nil;

    NSArray * goods = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest: goodsFetchRequest error:&error];

    NSSortDescriptor *categoryDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"category" ascending: YES ];
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"name" ascending: YES selector: @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    NSArray *sortedArray = [goods sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                            [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                             [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"category"
                                                           ascending:YES
                                                            selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]]];




       NSLog(@"------");
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.count; i++)
       {

          NSLog(@"%@", NSLocalizedString([[sortedArray objectAtIndex: i] category], nil));
       }

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[categoryDescriptor, nameDescriptor];

    [goodsFetchRequest setSortDescriptors: sortDescriptors];


    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: goodsFetchRequest managedObjectContext: context sectionNameKeyPath:@"category" cacheName: nil];

    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more precisely how you're testing this? I can't reproduce this. It sorts Блоки питания, Блоки питания, Видеокарты, Видеокарты, Звуковые карты, ... (which I believe is correct) in my tests on Mac and iOS in both English and Russian locales. Are you sure you're outputting `sortedArray` and not `goods`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` simply means that the locale will be consulted when considering whether one given string is less than another (i.e. whether "Ф" and "ф" are equivalent for "case insensitive" purposes). It does not cause the system to call `NSLocalizedString` on category for you.

My preferred solution would be to add translated properties to your model object:

```
@interface Good (Translated)
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *translatedCategory;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *translatedName;
@end

@implementation Good (Translated)    
- (NSString *)translatedCategory {
    return NSLocalizedString(self.category, nil);
}

- (NSString *)translatedName {
    return NSLocalizedString(self.name, nil);
}
@end
```

Then you can sort and display these translated properties. I like this approach because I think it makes the code very clear, and means you can implement caching or whatever if you wanted to, or add other property-specific logic. That said, there may be times you'd rather be able to sort based on translation. Or maybe you have a lot of these and want to avoid creating a ton of boilerplate (or fancy method forwarding tricks).

In that case you can use a custom sort descriptor with your own comparison rule. For a simple `NSArray`, you could use a comparator-based sort descriptor, but Core Data doesn't support blocks, so we'll need a special selector that we can call.

What we want is a comparison function that compares translated strings. We can make that by adding a category to `NSString` like this:

```
@interface NSString (MYTranslatedSorting)
- (NSComparisonResult)my_translatedCaseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)other;
@end

@implementation NSString (MYTranslatedSorting)

- (NSComparisonResult)my_translatedCaseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *)other {
    NSString *translatedSelf = NSLocalizedString(self, nil);
    NSString *translatedOther = NSLocalizedString(other, nil);
    return [translatedSelf localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:translatedOther];
}
@end
```

Now it's possible to call `[englishString my_translatedCaseInsensitiveCompare:otherEnglish]` and return the order based on the *translated* version. With that, we can use the following sort descriptors:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors =
@[
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category" ascending:YES selector:@selector(my_translatedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)],
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(my_translatedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)],
  ];
```

Comment: So is the array `goods` actually in English or in Russian? Your "whole code" doesn't match your "Im testing it by" code. (The latter has `NSLocalizedString` in it.) The list you gave looks sorted by English (I think: cooling fans, memory, microphones, ...), which makes me think `goods` is in English.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited. Array goods actually in English, but i have localizable.strings where i have translation for all words. Actually i want to use this "category" as tableView sections names.

Comment: Right; you just need to localize the strings before you compare them. See above.

Comment: If i just copy and paste this code, my app crashs with [Goods localizedCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fae5bf0f760'

Comment: The code was sorting strings, not "Goods" objects. See above. You shouldn't copy and paste it. It's worth typing and thinking what it's doing.

Comment: Yes, im understand, but when i copy-paste this code, my app crashes

Comment: Understood; I edited it to read the categories rather than just sort string.

Comment: Now it works, thanks. But can you help me to apply this to my categoryDescriptor please?

Comment: See `+sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:`. It should allow you to create a sort descriptor that works as you want.