# How can I sort an NSFetchedResultsController by localized values?

Tags: swift, core-data, localization, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm almost completely done localizing my app to support multiple languages but I've run into a sorting problem I can't solve.

I have this entity:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Lift {
    @NSManaged var liftName: String
    @NSManaged var uuid: String
    @NSManaged var custom: Bool
    @NSManaged var liftEvent: NSSet?
}
```

and I have this fetch request which I use in several places that fetches all the Lift objects:

```
func fetchSelectableLifts() -> NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> {
    var fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Lift")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "custom", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(key: "liftName", ascending: true)]
    
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(Lift.custom), cacheName: nil)
    
    try! fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    
    return fetchedResultsController
}
```

The problem is that I need to sort them by their ***localized***
`liftName` but I only store the names in English. It would impractical for me to store the names in multiple languages in Core Data.

Sort descriptor(s) must be specified when creating a `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` and because the names are stored in English, it can only be sorted by the English names. The result is this:

[image]

Is it possible to sort an `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>` after it's been fetched?

**EDIT 1**

```
extension Lift {
    @objc
    var localizedLiftName: String {
        get { NSLocalizedString(liftName, tableName: "liftLogModel", comment: "") }
    }
}
```

and used it like this in my fetchRequest:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Lift")
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "custom", ascending: true), NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Lift.localizedLiftName, ascending: true)]
```

It crashes at runtime with this error: `"Thread 1: "keypath localizedLiftName not found in entity Lift"`

Comment: You might be able to use the `NSSortDescriptor.init(key:ascending:selector:)` instead and put the localizedCompare in the selector, or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390174/sort-core-data-objects-by-translated-properties ?